# If I spin an electron gun fast enough, would it generate a significant magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons

I wondering if it possible for a beam of electrons to behave like a magnet, with that said, If I spin an electron gun fast enough, would it generate a significant magnetic field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A beam of electrons is moving charge. Moving charge is current. Current creates magnetic fields. Even a straight beam of electrons produces a magnetic field. See: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law). I'm not sure what spinning the electron gun around is supposed to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible. An electron beam is identical to a straight current carrying wire. We do know that magnetic field is created around the wire. However, its the magnitude of current which will decide the strength of magnetic field around these wires or electron beams.

For a current carrying loop, magnetic field at a distance $x$ from its centre is given by,

$B=\frac{\mu_{\circ}IR^2}{2(x^2+R^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

If you look at it, the strength depends on current which is defined as the charge passing through a point on the loop in unit time.

$I=\frac{q}{t}$

If you rotate a *charged wire* (without any current due to battery) with angular velocity $\omega$, you will have a system equivalent to a current carrying loop (with battery). In this case, the current will be given as,

$I=e.\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$

The relation means that the a particular point on the loop passes through its initial position $\frac{\omega}{2\pi}$ times in one second and if we multiply this by the charge of electron, e, we get the current defined as the charge passing through a point per sec.

It is worth mentioning that neutral wires when rotated do not produce any magnetic field because the field due to protons and electrons get cancelled out.